# Iterate over multiple dataframe rows at the same time

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset, pandas, preprocessing

I have 16 different dataframes with the same number of rows/columns and another 2 separate dataframes with that same shape that i'm using to compare with the 16 dataframe values.

I need to loop over all dataframes at the same time, and compare all row values with the separate dataframes, and then create another dataframe with the results like so:

comparison: `sum(row_values_of_dataframe) - sum(row_values_of_reference)`. In the example below, the cell `df_a_ref_a` is equal to $(1 + 2 + 3 + 4) - (5 + 5 + 5 + 5) = -10$

```py
Dataframe A (df_a)

col1 | col 2 | col 3 | col 4
1       2       3       4
2       4       6       8
[...]

Dataframe B (df_b)

col1 | col 2 | col 3 | col 4
10      5       2       1
4       4       6       2
[...]

Reference Dataframe 1 (ref_1)
col1 | col 2 | col 3 | col 4
5       5       5       5
5       5       5       5
[...]

Reference Dataframe 2 (ref_2)
col1 | col 2 | col 3 | col 4
3       3       3       3
3       3       3       3
[...]
```

Final dataframe should be:

```py
df_a_ref_1 | df_a_ref_2 | df_b_ref_1 | df_b_ref_2 | ....
    -10          -2           -2           6        ....
     0           8            -4           4
[...]
```

This behaviour resembles `zip()` function in python.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3):

First: I think you want the *product* functionality, not *zip*, since you are checking every `df` with every `ref`. In zip, you would check `df_a` with `ref_1` and `df_b` with `ref_2` only.

Second: Your can look at the equation $(1+2+3+4)−(5+5+5+5)$ as $(1-5) + (2-5) + ...$ which is simply subtracting data frames and sum over columns.

With these two consideration, assuming you have defined your objects as follows:

```
df_a = {
    'name': 'df_a',
    'value': pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 6, 8]])
}
df_b = {
    'name': 'df_b',
    'value': pd.DataFrame([[10, 5, 2, 1], [4, 4, 6, 2]])
}

ref_1 = {
    'name': 'ref_1',
    'value': pd.DataFrame([[5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5]])
}
ref_2 = {
    'name': 'ref_b',
    'value': pd.DataFrame([[3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3]])
}
```

I did this because I want to use the `name`s in creating the name of the columns of your final df. Then your code would be:

```
from itertools import product

final_result = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        '{}_{}'.format(df['name'], ref['name']): (df['value']-ref['value']).sum(axis=1)
        for (df, ref) in product([df_a, df_b], [ref_1, ref_2])
    }
)
```

- I have used dictionary comprehension to skip the ugly loop/append solution.
- `product` function from `itertools` does your iteration. product on `(ab, cd)` gives you `ac, ad, bc, bd`
- as for keys, df names are joined together with `_`, and as for values, I have subtracted two dfs and sum over columns (`axis=1`)

The result would then be as you expect:

```
   df_a_ref_1  df_a_ref_b  df_b_ref_1  df_b_ref_b
0         -10          -2          -2           6
1           0           8          -4           4
```

Still if you want to expand the dictionary comprehension or do not want to define dictionaries of `names/values`, of course you can imagine how you can write simple `for` loops with the same logic:

```
for (df, ref) in product([df_a, df_b], [ref_1, ref_2]):
    # your desired columns
    col = (df - ref).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Sorry, i must have said that these are not the actual values of the dataframes. That said, i don't have a dataframe of 5's to rewrite the equation like you said. However, i will do something like you proposed.

Comment: @heresthebuzz rewriting the equation has nothing to do with the real values. it's simple math. you apply negation to the values inside parenthesis and pack each negated value with the respective positive value. It'll work even if you have values other than 5 or anything else

Comment: And if the solution for a question is acceptable, then you might want to accept the solution as the final solution, so that the topic is concluded.